# How to get silent switch status in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I found out "Silent switch" status of Device using "AudioSessionGetProperty" before [iOS5]  released.

```
CFStringRef route;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &route);
if(CFStringGetLength(route) == 0) {
     // Silent Mode
}
```

Now, I'd like to know how to get "silent switch" status in "iOS5"

Comment: AudioSessionGetProperty is supported on iOS 5.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy : ok, but that old method does not work anymore

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Post the error message or whatever other problem you have.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy : route is now always filled with "Speaker". So that does not work anymore.

Comment: Looks like others have the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798891/detect-silent-mode-in-ios5

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. I've asked the question directly to Apple using a Developer Technical Support, and they answered me that the way that was made possible prior to iOS 5 was because of a breach, that was corrected in iOS 5. They say it's not made possible anymore, and if we want such a feature, we have to ask for it.

Comment: It's definitely possible, even in iOS5. Look at this (paid...) component. But I wanna figure that out, not pay for closed source stuff. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/vssilentswitch

Comment: @steipete:very very very interesting !

Comment: The component does some trick with playing a silent track and evaluating something. It has 1-2 seconds delay. Definitely a very crude hack.