# Get current sound volume in IOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I need to get current sound volume under my IOS5 application. The app is supposed to be used in cinemas so I want to notify the user that he/she should turn the volume down unless it is already turned down.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
musicPlayer = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

currentVolume = musicPlayer.volume;
```

Comment: This looks great but when the device is muted I still get the positive volume value. Looks as though muted state didn't affect volume value. Would it be possible to read also muted state under IOS5?

Comment: try using applicationMusicPlayer instead of iPodMusicPlayer and then check.. otherwise jbat100's answer looks pretty decent to me.

Comment: are you creating your own music player object or something like that... can you give us some code.

Comment: I am creating a software that will display content relevant to a movie being displayed in cinema. The requirement is to warn the user having unmuted device that he should mute it.

Comment: seems like this solution is no longer valid since iOS 7.0 :(   
  
_@property(nonatomic) float volume NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 7_0);"_

Answer (score 1):

You can get the volume like this

```
-(Float32)audioVolume
{
    Float32 state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    OSStatus n = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, &propertySize, &state);
    if( n )
    {
        // something didn't work...
    }
    return state;
}
```

You can get system volume updates like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(volumeChanged:) 
                                             name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

You can work out if the phone is in silent mode if this returns an empty string (this will crash if in the simulator hence the compile time guards).

```
#ifndef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
-(NSString*)audioRoute
{
    CFStringRef state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    OSStatus n = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
    if( n )
    {
        // something didn't work...
    }
    NSString *result = (NSString*)state;
    [result autorelease];
    return result;
} 
#endif
```

Although [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798891/detect-silent-mode-in-ios5), this will not work in iOS 5. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki) is related also.

Comment: Is it also possible to get updates about turning the mute button on and off?