# How to stop vibration when the silent switch is on?

Tags: iphone

I have the following code to vibrate

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

It vibrate even the silent switch is on. However, I don't want it to vibrate in silent mode. It's annoying. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the ringer state, right? If that's the case check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798891/detect-silent-mode-in-ios5)

Comment: pretty much. You can add a setting in your app.