# Detect silent mode in iOS6?

Tags: audio, notifications, ios6

Does anyone know if the answer to this question has changed in iOS6?

[Detect Silent mode in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798891/detect-silent-mode-in-ios5)

Comment: This seems to be the real answer: ["They've said they don't and never have provided a method for detecting hardware mute switch and don't intend to do so."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8009073/645270). But your question is still kinda valid :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. No more AV API for detecting silent switch status.