# How to know when user switches ring/silent (mute) button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is there some system notification that I can subscribe to be notified when user switches ring/silent button? I would also like to know whether Apple provides some "system notifications list" or not. I've spent an hour searching this but failed.

Comment: [Look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8036712/1263701)

Comment: Your awnser is too old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to find out that. Apple in response to some request has answered like this

> We never have provided a method for detecting hardware mute switch and don't intend to do so.

In case you would try some work around I think Apple will reject your application, however you could request for the feature or report a bug to apple.