# Check Device is Silent

Tags: ios, xcode, device, silent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect iphone is on silent mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode)

I made an iPhoneApplication which plays a sound if you shake it. My Problem is that many people that use it wonder why it doesnt play a sound if they shake while the device is simply in silent mode. I wanted to solve the problem by displaying an alert if the device is in silent mode.

My question is: "how can i check wether the device is in silent mode or not?"

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546582/check-if-ipad-is-in-silent-mode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798891/detect-silent-mode-in-ios5

Comment: okay. so its simply not possible!? didnt find this in my search

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch